# Problem with an array of a Class which I created in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to create an array of a type which I create.
Here's my problem:

```
public class MyFile
{        
     int page_no=23;
     Page[] pages_in_file;
     MyFile()
     {
         pages_in_file=new Page[page_no];
     }  
}
```

And Java gives error when debug comes to Page[] part and it does not even entes Page's constructor.
Page Class is this:

```
public class Page
{  
    String data=null;
    String contain=null;

Page()
{
    data = new String();
    contain = new String();
}
}
```

Error says : "Source not found" and gives this NullPointerException when I try to access an element in the array.
I guess I don't see an obvious error but i appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: What's the actual complete error message text and where do you declare and initialize the page_no variable?  **Edit 1:** I now see where you declare the page_no variable.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java only allocates the memory for your classes, it does not run the constructors when initialising the array. At a minimum, you will need to add:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pages_in_file.length; i++)
    pages_in_file[i] = new Page();
```

Comment: Actually, Java only allocates memory for an array of references. Those references are all set to `null`. To allocate the object itself and call its constructor, `new` has to be used.

Comment: @Etinne - That is exactly what I just said. Why do people feel the need to "correct" a statement that is already correct by saying exactly the same thing with slightly different wording? *facepalm*

Comment: This way, it gives NullPointerException.

Comment: OK I solved. I edited your answer and this works perfect. Thanks so much !

Comment: Joe: That is not exactly what you just said. Java only allocates memory for *objects* at the time it will run the constructor. When initializing the array it only allocates memory for the array, not for your *objects* (the word classes here makes no sense). People feel the need to correct a statement that is incorrect by saying similar things with different but correct wording.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing an array of objects does not imply construction of the objects. Therefore, your error is (most likely) that `page_no` is negative or otherwise unset. Unfortunately, your demo code does not include `page_no`'s definition and value.

Comment: I editied the code and I accidently removed that line. page_no is 23.

Answer (score -3):

It is because of the File class. Java has a class named File already and it is a final class, so you need to rename your File class to something else.

Comment: Nope, class names don't have to be unique across namespaces in Java. After all, what would be the purpose of namespaces if they weren't?

Comment: No. `File` is in the `java.io` package. It won't conflict with this one.

Comment: Though your probably **should** rename this class as its name would tend to confuse many of us.

Comment: @cantbereached: that's because as noted by the first two comments to this answer, your error isn't due to a naming issue.